# How do i make a count down timer continue to count down when the app is reloaded

Tags: java, android, timer

In my android app I have an object which has a method which has a timer inside it. And when the method is called everything works perfectly. The count down timer in the method keeps replaying over and over again which is good but when the app is closed completely and re opened again the timer that was in the method does not keep replaying like it was before. How do i make it so the app can check if it was replaying before and if so make it replay now so it was like the timer continues to replay itself over again.

So basically: How do i make the count down timer continue to count down when the app is reloaded.

method below

```
 public int shipAdd() {
    if (counter >= addSpend) {

        counter -= addSpend;

        addSpend += addSpend;

        counterPerSec +=addAmount;

        addClick += addClick;

        test++;

        // The count down timer below 

        new TimerClass(addTime, 1000) {

            public void onFinish() {

                counter += addAmount;
                this.start();

            }
        }.start();

    } else if (counter < addSpend) {

    }
    return addSpend;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use something called sharedpreferences, with this you could save where you stopped last time and pick it up from there. Also you could check if you've got a place to pick up from. 
you can read more here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I know how to use SharedPrefences but how do i make it save it and replay it?

Comment: Personally i would make a variable like int a = 1; or something when you have it started. And you just save other variables into it, and then get them again. It'll remember where you stopped etc. Only way i know how, not sure if there even is another one.